# google pagespeed need to fix

Tags: pagespeed, mod-pagespeed, google-pagespeed

I have a problem with google pagespeed.
I was editing .php file with sublime text 2, and it installed pagespeed automatically.

Before that my javascript and css files was look like:

```
jquery.fancybox.js
jquery.bxslider.min.js
swfobject.min.js
style.css
```

Now it's look like:

```
jquery.fancybox.js.pagespeed.jm.BrR0tLMtrF.js
jquery.bxslider.min.js.pagespeed.jm.3ZM6Lzd20m.js
swfobject.min.js.pagespeed.jm.QLhLISEJF7.js
A.style.css,qv4.pagespeed.cf.xLVw-90KTM.css
```

How can I fix that?

Comment: Can you clarify if you are using [mod_pagespeed](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/module) or [PageSpeed Service](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/module)?

Comment: I haven't installed any of them, but I'll check. Can you tell me how to check this?

Comment: You must have one of them setup if you are seeing .pagespeed. resources on your site. You can check the response headers for your page and you should see an X-Mod-Pagespeed header if you have mod_pagespeed, or an X-PageSpeed header if your page is being served through PageSpeed Service.

Answer (score 0):

This is how mod_pagespeed (or PageSpeed Service) is supposed to act, it rewrite URLs on your page to make the website faster. Is this causing rendering problems for your site? Are you trying to uninstall?

Comment: i am trying to uninstall. i am getting 403 error in console for some necessary files